# Blue Circle is displayed in CircleAvatar Asset image instead of real image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, flutter-image

I am trying to display the image in the Card widget in leading CircleAvatar below is my code

```
child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            title: Text(locations[index].location.toString()),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 18.0,
              backgroundImage:
                  AssetImage('assets/${locations[index].flag}'),)
```

Instead of the real image, I want to show, Blue color is displayed in the circle as shown in below attachment
[image]

Comment: are these assets listed in your `pubspec.yaml` file under `assets:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, make you have added image on `pubspec.yaml`.
- while loading data from asset, do restart the app, not hot reload or restart.
- if it fails, do `flutter clean` and run again.
- else, make sure about image path.
- also check this [doc for supported image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) in flutter

Comment: Restarting the app work for me, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add this to CircleAvatar
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

Answer (score -1):

Remember this principle in your pubspec.yaml file

asset #(1 tab or 2 whitespaces)
- assets/ #(2 tabs or 4 whitespaces)

This worked for me!